# Randomly Generated search term error

Tags: java, random

I'm working on a problem that involves me generating a certain number of numbers (here named "Jeff") and searching through them, then recording the time, in order to learn how long it takes to do the task with different searching algorithms. Below you'll find what I have so far, excluding the binarySearch algorithm (which works). The problem that I've found is that the "searched value" is coming up as "Not Found" each time.

I took code that accepted a Jeff amount of numbers (that were user input) then a user-chosen search term. I changed it so that the randomly generated numbers would fill the List fully, but that stopped the search from working. Or that's what it seems.

Anything helps!

Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    int Jeff = 20;

    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Jeff);
    int searchValue = 0, index;
    int temp;

    Random generator = new Random();

    System.out.println("Entering " + Jeff + " numbers...");
    //Adds unique values up to and through Jeff
    while (intList.size() < Jeff) {
            Integer next = generator.nextInt(Jeff) + 1;
            if (!intList.contains(next))
            {
                // Done for this iteration
                intList.add(next);
            }
    }
    System.out.println("List: " + intList);

    //Adding to ArrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++) {
        temp = generator.nextInt(Jeff) + 1;
        intList.set(i,temp);
    }
    System.out.print("Enter a number to search for: ");
    searchValue = generator.nextInt(Jeff) + 1;
    System.out.println(searchValue);

    index = binarySearch(intList, searchValue);

    if (index != -1) {
        System.out.println("Found at index: " + index);
    } 
    else {
        System.out.println("Not Found");
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration1 = endTime - startTime;
    System.out.println(duration1);
    }
  static int binarySearch(List<Integer> intList, int find) {
    long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    int start, end, midPt;
    start = 0;
    end = intList.size() - 1;
    while (start <= end) {
        midPt = (start + end) / 2;
        if (intList.get(midPt) == find) {
            long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
            long duration2 = endTime2 - startTime2;
            System.out.println(duration2);
            return midPt;
        } else if (intList.get(midPt) < find) {
            start = midPt + 1;
        } else {
            end = midPt - 1;
        }
    }
    long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();
    long duration2 = endTime2 - startTime2;
    System.out.println(duration2);
    return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the Code for binary search.

Comment: I know that isn't the issue, but I can post that as well.
Here it is!

Comment: Binary search needs all the elements in the list to be sorted. If you're just filling the list with random data, that's very unlikely to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're filling your list with random numbers. Unfortunately, that doesn't work so well with a binary search.

For example, imagine `Jeff = 5`. Your list might look like the following after you've added your random numbers:

```
[3, 1, 5, 2, 4]
```

Now if you search for 2, you first look at the element at the midpoint of the list which is 5.  Since 2 is less than 5, you then proceed to look for it in the left half of the list (i.e. `[3, 1]`). Obviously, it's not there and your search will therefore fail.

You need to sort your list first (which makes the solution trivial, unfortunately), or pick a new search strategy. For a non-trivial search on a sorted list, you could search over a sorted list of integers that are not restricted to `1 <= n <= Jeff`.

---

P.S. Please don't call your variables "Jeff". It might be kind of endearing, but it's also not a good habit to get into as it hampers readability.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Why would it come up with the wrong index then, regardless of it's proper order?

Comment: If your search code is OK, then it shouldn't come up with the wrong index even if the list is random. You might still be lucky and find your target value (e.g. you might be able to find 1 in my example above), but most likely you'll just not find your target value at all. If you're coming up with the wrong index, there's some other issue with your search implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the searchValue is in intList?  It looks like it ought to be

```
searchValue = intList.get(generator.nextInt(intList.size()));
```

Comment: That still comes up as "Not Found" half the time. It should always be found.